# Can I set any of these statements in php.ini

Tags: php, session

I have the following code in one of the php files:

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', false);
    session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
    session_cache_expire(7200);   // minutes
```

and wonder whether I can remove any of these statements and move them in php.ini file. After searching for something similar I have not found anything.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Did you check the manual? For example, for [session_cache_expire](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php), it says "The cache expire is reset to the default value of 180 stored in session.cache_expire at request startup time", and [links to](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire) that setting's entry in the php.ini runtime configuration page.

Comment: Open your `php.ini` file and search for "session"! Most of them (if not all) can be set there. Don't be lazy.

Comment: @GhostGambler please post this as an answer (I will accept it).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen sorry. Apparently I am too sleepy to code now (because I actually spent some time searching and apparently failed).

Comment: @SalvadorDali It's okay. Just accept one of the other answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the documentation of the ini settings corresponding to the function calls [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

Quote from the docs:

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

Answer (score 3):

You may check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) which says about all of them. For example:

> **[session_cache_expire](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php)**
>
> The cache expire is reset to the default value of 180 stored in
> session.cache_expire at request startup time